# HTTP authorization in header is basic by default and throws http500 if mentioned

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, basic-authentication

I have an OData interface with an implemented basic authentication. Somehow the basic auth is set to default by its class. When I deliver the credentials in the request header without the key word "Basic", it works fine, but when I do, I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.
How can I remove the default basic auth setting?

works:
[image: picture of auth checkbox]

does not work, like it should:
[image: auth checkbox with basic setting]

This is my auth class:

```cs
public class HttpBasicAuthorizeAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute {

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        Debug.WriteLine(actionContext.Request.Headers);
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null) {
            // get the Authorization header value from the request and base64 decode it
                            
            string userInfo = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString()));
            // custom authentication logic
            if (string.Equals(userInfo,string.Format("{0}:{1}","name","=password"))) {
                IsAuthorized(actionContext);
            }
            else {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
        }
        else {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
            ReasonPhrase = "Unauthorized"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an attribute not an authentication class. It's not needed by HttpClient or any ASP.NET OData stack either. Authentication is handled by the web server, not the OData classes

Comment: `System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext` is part of a discontinued version of ASP.NET Web API stack, which [already supports Basic Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) both at the IIS and project level. Why are you trying to roll your own?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to pass an Authorization header value is 'Basic {base64string}' and based on the image you shared in the question, the right way is causing an Internal Server Error for you.
That's because the output of  `actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString()` is not a valid Base64 string as it contains the 'Basic ' string literal in it. Before you apply `Convert.FromBase64String()` on it, you will need to remove the 'Basic ' literal from it.

Applying an additional `.Replace("Basic ", string.Empty)` at the end of `ToString()` would do it. Should look like this-

```
string userInfo = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Replace("Basic ", string.Empty)));
```

Comment: Now it's working in both ways, thanks. Simply out of curiosity, what can I do to deactivate the Basic auth as default, so that I have to write Basic in the header request?

Comment: Not sure how that implementation of OData is happening. There doesn't seem to be enough context provided in the question about it.

Comment: @Broda why do you want to disable authentication and why do you assume the service will accept anonymous calls?

Comment: I don't want to disable authentication. The problem is, that I don't need to write "Basic " before the credentials.